# Batch Delete a line in a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I'm pulling my hair out finding a simple example of a DOS batch file that will delete the first line of several thousand txt files and save the file with the original file name. Following a batch process performed by another program, I then have to ADD the deleted line ( a text string consisting of "X,Y,Z") at the beginning of each file following the external processing.

Comment: So, to be more clear, all you want to be done is to replace the first line of each of those thousands of text files with the same line "X, Y, Z" (or whatever).

Comment: @adarshr: Nope, I guess the other problem he mentions requires that the first line is not present and after that ran it should be re-added.

Comment: exactly. The "other software" will choke with the first line of "X,Y,Z", so it has to be removed, to be readded when the "other software" finishes its thing, which will take days given the number of input files. Thankfully I've allready managed to write a batch for that task.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `more +1` to skip the first line of the file. Then you can pipe it into a temporary one (you cannot edit text files in place):

```
for %x in (*.txt) do (more +1 "%x">tmp & move /y tmp "%x")
```

After that you can use a similar technique to re-add the first line:

```
for %x in (*.txt) do ((echo X,Y,Z& type "%x")>tmp & move /y tmp "%x")
```

If you use those in a batch file, remember to double the `%` signs:

```
@echo off
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    more +1 "%%x" >tmp
    move /y tmp "%%x"
)
rem Run your utility here
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    echo X,Y,Z>tmp
    type "%%x" >>tmp
    move /y tmp "%%x"
)
```

Ok, apparently `more` doesn't work with too large files, which surprises me. As an alternative, which should work if your file does not contain blank lines (though it looks like CSV from what I gathered):

```
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%l in ("%%x") do (>>tmp echo.%%l)
    move /y tmp "%%x"
)
```

Comment: @echo off
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    more +1 "%%x" >tmp
    move /y tmp "%%x"
)
locks up when I move this to production files. Each file is from 5-20 MB in size. The tmp file grows to 2241 kb and thats where it stops working.

Comment: @Tom: I added another approach, untested yet, but I currently lack the time to thoroughly test. This approach should be much slower, though, sadly.

Comment: @Joey: I tried your script, but I was running in the same problem as @Tom, namely that it just didn't work for larger files. Your second approach (the one without `more`), however, doesn't do anything when I try to run it. Do you have any idea why? Basically, the only thing I changed was to replace `.txt` by `.csv` in the first line because I want to delete the first line of every csv-file. However, nothing happens (if I look at the save time of the files, this doesn't change, so I guess they are not opened). Would be great if you might have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version.

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b *.txt`) do (
    echo X, Y, Z>"tmp.txt"
    type "%%f" >> tmp.txt
    move tmp.txt "%%f"
)
```

Comment: `for` can iterate over lists of files just fine without needing to parse `dir`'s output (which can also fail miserably with Unicode file names in certain circumstances). Furthermore you're missing the removal of the first line.

Comment: Nope! Spoke to soon! @echo off
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    more +1 "%%x" >tmp
    move /y tmp "%%x"
)